# django automatically import module of a package,

Tags: python, django, import, init

Python does not automatically import subpackages or modules. We have to do it explicitly,
But why Django automatically import submodule of a package.

```
users/
    __init__.py (empty file)
    models.py
    views.py
```

in Django's Python manage.py shell:

```
    >>>import users
    >>>users.models.User     (will not throw AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute)
```

But when not in Django:

```
package1/
    __init__.py (empty file)
    module1.py
    >>>import package1
    >>>package1.module1  
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module1'
```

Can anyone explain the differences?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `manage.py` script sets up your Django environment before passing control to the Python shell. The shell is not a separate invocation of the `python` executable; it is executed by the same Python interpreter running the `manage.py` script itself. At the point where the shell is invoked, Django has already loaded its configuration and initialized all enabled applications, so all of their `models.py` submodules are already loaded.

When the same module is imported in several locations (e.g. `import users`), it is not loaded multiple times; the module instance itself will be the same in all places it is imported. Since Django itself has already imported `users.models` during its initialization, the existing `users` module instance already contains a reference to the already imported `users.models` submodule, and you can access it right away without importing it explicitly.